# Jest not returning exit codes

Tags: typescript, express, jestjs, github-actions, supertest

I've trying to run tests for my Express + TS application through GitHub Actions

But even if my test fails, it seems Jest doesn't return a non-zero exit code so the GitHub Action workflow doesn't fails and it looks like the tests passed when they didn't

My workflow:

```
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
        
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16.5.0
 
      - name: Installing dependencies
        run: npm install

      - name: Running tests
        run: npm test
```

My test suite example:

```
const app: Application = Server.createServer();
const server: SuperTest<Test> = supertest(app);

const mainGetUrl: string = '/api/v1';
describe('Get server main endpoint', (): void => {
  it(`GET ${mainGetUrl}`, async () => {
    const res: Response = await server.get(mainGetUrl);
    expect(res.status).toEqual(200);
    expect(res.type).toEqual(expect.stringContaining('json'));
  });
});
```

I'm using `"jest": "^27.1.4"` and running the test with `./node_modules/.bin/jest --testTimeout=10000`

Comment: Have you tried to reduce the timeout, or remove it just to see if that is the cause for the pipeline not failing?

Comment: So you're saying `npm test` doesn't return non-zero if some of your tests fail? If so, please change your question as it has nothing to do with github actions. After that, please show what the jest command returns.